# apply css on page load to all DIV elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onload, dynamic-css

Is there a way to format all my  tags in a page,  on page load, with a css property like this ?

```
border:1px #000000;
```

Also, on hover of any of the DIV, the border should change to this :

```
border : 1px #00800;
```

I want both these properties, regular CSS and on-hover CSS to be applied on page load, dynamically.

Comment: Could you clarify the 'on page load dynamically part?' I am genuinely confused.

Comment: If you really want to do it, you could use jQuery to add the classes after page load, but why would you ever want to do that? A more elaborate question might prevent the downvotes.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS for this? You can control both of these with straight CSS styles.

Comment: Thanks.. I found it was not that difficult after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet might work:

```
$(document).ready(function()//When the dom is ready or just add it if you already have a .ready function
{
  $("#div").css("border","1px #000000");
  $('#div').mouseover(function (e) {
   $("#div").css("border","1px #00800");
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you want to be looking for elements with the `id` of div. Removing the `#` is probably more what you're looking for. Also, this will set the border of all the divs when any of them have a mouse over them and it won't unset the property when the mouse leaves the div. Perhaps I misunderstood the question though.

Comment: @Mark... you are right... It didn't leave on mouseout. So I added another function on load for mouseout. And yes I did want it on ALL the div elements. Thanks

Comment: I would take Marat Tanalin's advice and use CSS to do this. I ran into a major performance issue a while back due to $(document).ready() listeners and believe me it is better to go with CSS over Javascript, especially if it is an easy method such as his suggestion is.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need JavaScript for that. Just add the following lines to your CSS:

```css
DIV {border: 1px #000; }
DIV:hover {border-color: #008000; }
```

Also, in practice, it’s unlikely that *all* `DIV` elements on your page could need such styles, so it’s better to use a class selector instead of a tag-name selector and use that class solely for elements that really need these styles:

```css
.example {border: 1px #000; }
.example:hover {border-color: #008000; }
```

```html
<div class="example">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript method on page load and apply these css properties there.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a listener for the ondevice ready event:

```
// listen to the device ready event.
document.addEventListener( "deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false );
```

then in the OnDeviceReady function you can do the js part of it

```
function OnDeviceReady()
{
    elements.style.border = '1px solid red';
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In document.ready add:

```
 $("*").css("border","1px #000000");
```

Above is for css

For hover

```
  $('#div').mouseover(function (e) {
    $("#div").css("border","1px #00800");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // all html element
    $('*').css('border', '1px #000000');

    // hover div
    $('div').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px #00800');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px #000000');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function in body using onload. and then in the func u can easily give the css for all required fields